# With css or styled-components, is it possible at hover to apply style on items visually displayed on the same column while laying on different lines?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm wondering if while hovering an element with a certain class, I can target all the elements with the same class, even if there don't necessarily have a relationship (parent-child, siblings..)

I know it could be done using `js`, but I would like to make it work with css for performance reasons.

So, in the following gif,
I would like to apply the same yellow background color for `.Col1` items if I hover the `.Col1` in either Line 1 or Line 2. Same for the other "columns".

[image]

Here are the `styled-components`

```js
const WrapperLines = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  & > * {
    :not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
`;

const Line = styled.div`
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Column = styled.div`
  margin: 20px;
  
`;

const Div = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  ${(props) => css`
      ${props.primary}:hover & {
      background: yellow;
    }
    `};
`;
```

And here is the `jsx`

```js
<WrapperLines>
    <Line className="line1">
      <Column className="col1">
        <Div primary={'.col1'}> Line 1 Col 1 </Div>
      </Column>
      <Column className="col2">
        <Div primary={'.col2'}> Line 1 Col 2 </Div>
      </Column>
      <Column className="col3">
        <Div primary={'.col3'}> Line 1 Col 3 </Div>
      </Column>
    </Line>
    <Line className="line2">
      <Column className="col1">
        <Div primary={'.col1'}> Line 2 Col 1 </Div>
      </Column>
      <Column className="col2">
        <Div primary={'.col2'}> Line 2 Col 1 </Div>
      </Column>
      <Column className="col3">
        <Div primary={'.col3'}> Line 2 Col 1 </Div>
      </Column>
    </Line>
</WrapperLines>
```

Project can be found on the following Stackblitz
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with just css.

But you can easily do it with JS, something like:

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');

// Add event listeners to each square on each row
rows.forEach((row) => {
  row.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach((square, i) => {
    square.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      handleMouseEnter(i);
    });
    square.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
  })
})

// add "active' attribute on all the sqaures on all the rows with same index of the hovered square
function handleMouseEnter(activeIndex) {
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    row.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach((square, i) => {
      if (i === activeIndex) {
        square.setAttribute('active', '');
      } else {
        square.removeAttribute('active');
      }
    })
  })
}

// remove "active" attribute from all squares
function handleMouseLeave(event) {
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    row.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach((square, i) => {
      square.removeAttribute('active');
    })
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square[active] {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="row">
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 1</div>
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 2</div>
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 2</div>
</section>

<section class="row">
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 1</div>
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 2</div>
  <div class="square">Line 1 col 2</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, I know it is doable in js, but it could cause performance issues in some cases. Anyway thanks for your answer, I guess it can't be achieved using css only.

Comment: I don't think you would get any performance issue with this. CSS only you could highlight the 2nd row when you hover the 1st, but not the other way around